# Profiling / Debugging a slow django request

Tags: python, django

I have a page running on my local django dev server with the Django Debug Toolbar that seems to be running quite slowly but I'm unsure why:

Django Debug Toolbar says

```
Resource    Value
User CPU time   1317.854 msec
System CPU time 191.942 msec
Total CPU time  1509.796 msec
Elapsed time    1473.806 msec
Context switches    6 voluntary, 16842 involuntary
```

SQL - 46 queries in 39.80ms

And then running a profiler https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/shaunsephton/django-snippetscream/.PipPackage/django-snippetscream/.def/snippetscream/_186/ProfileMiddleware

I get 7926 function calls (7774 primitive calls) in 0.024 seconds

So I'm left wondering why is the profile time so much lower than the Total CPU Time?

And then how can I find out what's causing the difference?

And secondary to that - should i be worried about the 16842 involuntary context switches!?

Comment: try running the profiler with debug = false, you'd be surprised how much overhead the debug mode causes :-)

Comment: Can you post up the view?

Comment: Hm.. have just tried outputting the total response time without the debug toolbar and it's zipping along - 160ms. Debug true/false doesn't cause too much difference.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out.. I seem to be in the same situation